# What an "allocator aware type" in C++?

Tags: c++, types, allocator

I am trying to figure out what is an "Allocator-Aware Type".
I found the name in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LAsqp7UrNs

Answer (score 3):

An allocator is an object or class that handles the details of allocating and freeing memory.  An allocator-aware type would be a class that is able to use a custom allocator to allocate memory for itself instead of just using the standard allocators provided by the C++ language (i.e. `malloc`, `free`, `new`, `delete`).

Comment: See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator